# How do you test an iOS framework

Tags: ios, testing, frameworks

I am developing an iOS framework. My question is how do I test it in a dummy app. Ideally in the same project window

Comment: please offer more context. have you approached UT/UITests/integration tests? Are you referring to black box testing? You can add additional Projects to your workspace and those can include your framework but it is unclear what situation you are having

Comment: no I want to build an iOS app within the framework project so I can test framework functionality

Comment: I think you have to do it the other way around. create the app and add the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you have to split into two scenarios.

1. Your framework contains functionality only.
   In that case I suggest to add a unit test target and test your framework by writing unit tests.
2. Your framework contains a ui component.
   In that case I suggest to add an application target and name it ExampleApp or something like that. In that app you can implement a visual example.

Both scenarios are used in open source GitHub repositories.